# Looping command through multiple workbooks in a folder

Tags: excel, for-loop, vba

**Background**
First of all I realise all of this is a perfect task for a database but I don't currently have that option available and I think it's a good learning experience to continue doing this in excel.

I have multiple workbooks each containing a list of identifying numbers, through the code below I enter the name of the workbook I require and the list is imported to main my workbook containing multiple columns of data. I then ran my [Match and Export sub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297551/matching-two-data-lists-in-excel-vba-and-exporting-to-new-sheet) to break up the main data set into different sheets.

**Question**
Is there a way to use a for loop for each of the files in the containing folder so that I don't have to identify each workbook in turn?

```
Sub Export_Specified_Contractor()

    Dim listwb As Workbook, mainwb As Workbook
    Dim fname As String
    Dim sht As Worksheet, oput As Worksheet
    Dim LRow As Long, oLRow As Long
    Dim cprng As Range, orng As Range

    '--> Get the name of the contractor list to be exported
    fname = Application.InputBox("Enter Contractor Name", "Name?")

    Set mainwb = ThisWorkbook

    With Application

    '--> Set contractor list file
    Set listwb = .Workbooks.Open _
    ("C:\Documents and Settings\alistairw\My Documents\Disallowed Items\Contractor Lists\" & fname)
    End With

    Set sht = listwb.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '--> Copy contractor list
    With sht
        LRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A1:A" & LRow).Copy
    End With

    mainwb.Activate

    '--> Create contractor list sheet in main workbook and paste values
    With mainwb
        On Error Resume Next
        Sheets("Sheet2").Delete
        Sheets.Add.Name = "Sheet2"
        Set oput = Sheets("Sheet2")
        With oput
            .Range("A1").PasteSpecial
        End With
    End With

    Call Match_and_Export

    '--> Delete the list workbook and list sheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    listwb.Close
    oput.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This should get you started http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898782/get-the-data-from-excel-files-in-sub-directories/10903402#10903402

Comment: This question has been asked many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looping through a folder:

```
MyPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\alistairw\My Documents\Disallowed Items\Contractor Lists\"
strFilename = Dir(MyPath & "\*.xlsx", vbNormal) 'change to xls if needed

If Len(strFilename) = 0 Then Exit Sub ' exit if no files in folder

Do Until strFilename = ""
    'Your code here
    strFilename = Dir()    
Loop
```

Comment: +1 - Nice and clean. It seems like this is getting asked a lot in the last few days.

Comment: Sorry took so long to accept this got sidetracked on another project. This works perfectly.